How do I update the numbers in this clock in p5js?
I'm attempting to make a clock using p5js with 3 continuously rotating rings which have the current hour/minute/second at the top of each ring. At the moment I'm just trying to figure out the seconds ring, assuming I can work out the details for the other two rings from there. I'm able to initially draw all the numbers along the ring, and I can get the ring to rotate at the right pace, but the numbers don't update correctly. I think I just need to update the number at the bottom, but I'm not sure how to handle it since the text function doesn't return any sort of manipulatable object. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as my head can't take much more beating on the desk.
Here's the relevant code. The white number in the corner is the current second. It's just there for reference. As for the ring, I'm planning to hide the lower half off screen, so the disconnect at the bottom is intentional. It works if I fill it with all numbers 0-59, but trying to squeeze 60 numbers along the ring looks horrendous, hence why I'm hoping to only display the current second±12. The trueMod function (included in Ring.js) is the same as the % operator, but handles negative numbers correctly.


// ring.js
function trueMod(value, modulus) {
  /* Builtin mod doesn't work for negative numbers. */
  return ((value % modulus) + modulus) % modulus;
}

class Ring {
  /* radius: The radius of the ring.
   * modulus: The modulus for the numbers along the ring.
   * fillColor: The color of the ring.
   * update: Function used to update the numbers.
   */
  constructor(radius, modulus, fillColor, update) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.modulus = modulus;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    this.update = update;
    this.numSlices = 24; // number of numbers to display along the ring
  }

  draw() {
    push();

    fill(this.fillColor);
    circle(0, 0, this.radius * 2 + 40);
    rotate(millis() / 1000 * -TAU / this.numSlices);

    fill(255);
    let t = -TAU / 4;
    let step = TAU / this.numSlices;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.numSlices / 2; i++) {
      push();
      translate(this.radius * cos(t), this.radius * sin(t));
      rotate(i * step);
      text(
        String(trueMod(this.update() + i, this.modulus)).padStart(2, "0"), 0, 0
      );
      t += step;
      pop();
    }
    for (let i = this.numSlices / 2; i > 0; i--) {
      push();
      translate(this.radius * cos(t), this.radius * sin(t));
      rotate(-i * step);
      text(
        String(trueMod(this.update() - i, this.modulus)).padStart(2, "0"), 0, 0
      );
      t += step;
      pop();
    }
    pop();
  }
}

// sketch.js
let secondRing;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  secondRing = new Ring(
    windowHeight * 6 / 16,
    60,
    color(0x57, 0x75, 0x90),
    second
  );
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize((windowHeight * 1) / 30);
  fill(255);
  text(second(), 50, 50);
  translate(windowWidth / 2, windowHeight / 2);
  secondRing.draw();
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.9.0/p5.js"></script>




Thanks. The example works now. I guess I'm not clear on the expected behavior though. Can you clarify?

As the wheel turns, it should show the current second at the top. It works for the first few numbers, but then no longer updates correctly. It's like the numbers are only drawn once and then never update again.

Oh yeah, looking at it carefully I see the problem. Thanks.

Well this is redundant, isn't it?  Or you change the numbers or you turn the wheel. I mean, if you  just don't update the numbers they will be right. Or, if don't turn the wheel they will be all right also... aren't they?

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but I'm planning to only use 24 numbers along the wheel, not all 60. I tried with all 60, and that does technically work, but it looks awful because the numbers are too close together. But when there's only 24 numbers, you only have the initial second value ±12. If you don't update the numbers somehow, then you'd be missing several of the numbers and the wheel would very quickly no longer show the correct second value. Hopefully that makes sense.
